# nltk.cluster using a sparse representation

Tags: python, nltk

I am quite new in Python.

I am trying to use the nltk.cluster package to apply a simple kMeans to a word-document matrix. While it works when the matrix is a list of numpy array-like objects, I wasn't able to make it work for a sparse matrix representation (such as csc_matrix, csr_matrix or lil_matrix).

All the information that I found was:

> Note that the vectors must use numpy array-like objects. nltk_contrib.unimelb.tacohn.SparseArrays may be used for efficiency when required

I do not understand what this means. Can anyone help me in this matter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It means that when you pass in the input vector, you can either pass in a numpy.array() or a nltk_contrib.unimelb.tacohn.SparseArrays.

I suggest you look at the package **nltk_contrib.unimelb.tacohn** to find the SparseArrays class. Then try to create your data with this class before passing it into nltk.cluster

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to download the package nltk_contrib.unimelb.tacohn (although it doesn't seem to be a very popular package). When I pass in the input vector with a nltk_contrib.unimelb.tacohn.SparseArrays format to the "nltk.cluster" function, many errors arises because this function is still trying to use the numpy.array methods. I was able to modify the dot product, so that it can use the one provided in the SparseArrays class, but then another error arises. So I am not sure about how to solve this problem properly.

Comment: Could you edit your original question to include what you have tried, the code and some URLs? Perhaps I can give it a test on my computer.